# Running DataTables' ajax() function when updating table

Tags: datatables

I have a DataTables where I'm taking additional actions on the AJAX returned data, per [the docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax), like:

```
var table = $('#statstable').DataTable( {
    ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/stats/2020/01/",
        }).then ( function(json) {
            var data = json;
            $("#total_in_month").text(json.total_in_month);
            callback(data);

        });
    },
    search: false,
);
```

The source I'm using is formatted as such:

```
{
    "total_in_month": 1636, 
    "data": [
        {"total_on_date": 47, "date": "01-01-2020", "externals": 1}, 
        {"total_on_date": 47, "date": "02-01-2020", "externals": 1}, 
        {"total_on_date": 48, "date": "03-01-2020", "externals": 1}, 
        {"total_on_date": 48, "date": "04-01-2020", "externals": 1}, 
        {"total_on_date": 49, "date": "05-01-2020", "externals": 1}, 
        {"total_on_date": 48, "date": "06-01-2020", "externals": 3}, 
        {"total_on_date": 47, "date": "07-01-2020", "externals": 3}, 
        {"total_on_date": 48, "date": "08-01-2020", "externals": 1}, 
        ...
    ]
}
```

Everything works, i.e. my DataTable is populated properly and the span `total_in_month` is updated properly when the page is loaded.

However I'd like to dynamically change the data in the table, but also in the span 'total_in_month' outside of the table.

So I was using something like `$("#statstable").DataTable().ajax.url("/api/stats/" + year + "/" + month + "/").load();`, which works, but that doesn't allow me to update `total_in_month`.

Any idea how this can be approached?

I tried calling  `$('#statstable').DataTable( { ajax: function (data, callback, settings) { ...` again but that yields an error `Cannot reinitialise DataTable`.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "dynamically change the data" - but maybe all you need is `table.ajax.reload();`. The [`reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) call will re-execute the `ajax` option in your DataTable definition. It will fetch the latest data from the URL and also update the external span.

Comment: A `table.ajax.url()` followed by a `table.ajax.reload()` seems to have the same effect as `table.ajax.url().load()`. When re-doing the json request, I would like to receive the json data once, and update both the table /and/ the `#total_in_month` span, like I do with the `ajax: function (data, callback, settings)` call when initially loading the table.

Comment: OK understood - I have provided an approach which combines `table.ajax.reload()` with the use of a variable for the URL. This avoids needing to use `table.ajax.url()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variable for your URL source, together with `table.ajax.reload()`, to re-populate both the table and the span each time, from a new URL:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // my test URLs are http://localhost:7000/stats/1 and http://localhost:7000/stats/2
  var base_url = "http://localhost:7000/stats/";
  var full_url = base_url + '1';
 
  var table = $('#statstable').DataTable( {
    ajax: function (data, callback, settings) {
      $.ajax({
        url: full_url,
      }).then ( function(json) {
        var data = json;
        //console.log( json.total_in_month );
        $("#total_in_month").text(json.total_in_month);
        callback(data);
      });
    },

    search: false,
    columns: [
      { data: "total_on_date" },
      { data: "date" },
      { data: "externals" }
    ]
  });

  // a demo of changing the URL and re-displaying the table and span
  // data from the new URL:
  setInterval( function () {
    full_url = base_url + '2';
    table.ajax.reload();
  }, 3000 );

} );
```

In my case, I have used a simple test URL with only one variable:

```
var base_url = "http://localhost:7000/stats/";
var full_url = base_url + '1';
```

You would need to adjust that for your URL, `year` and `month` values.

In my example code, just for demonstration purposes, the page is populated from `http://localhost:7000/stats/1`, and after 3 seconds, the page is automatically updated with data from `http://localhost:7000/stats/2`. This applies to both the table and span.